# I want to show data according to true and false in Angular

Tags: angular

I am new to angular, Here I want to show user list if check is true and data not available if check is false, but datas are displaying for both false and true

Here I am adding my ts file and html file

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { UserDataService } from '../services/user-data.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-users',
  templateUrl: './users.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./users.component.css']
})
export class UsersComponent implements OnInit {
  check: any = false;
  pageTitle = 'Users List';
  errorMessage = '';
  //users: IUser[]=[];
  users: any;
  constructor(private userService: UserDataService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.userService.users().subscribe({
      next: (users: any) => {
        this.users = users;
        this.check = true;
        console.log("this.users");
        console.log(this.users);
      },
      error: (err: any) => this.errorMessage = err


    })
  }

}
```

```
<p>users works!</p>
<div>*********************User Component*******************</div>
<p>{{check}}</p>
<div *ngIf="!check">Data not available</div>
<ul *ngIf="check">
    <li *ngFor="let user of users">
        {{user.name}}
    </li>

</ul>
```

Comment: I have written code like this before, and it should work this way. Can you prepare a reproduction? There are tools like StackBlitz which should make it quite easy.

Answer (score 0):

`*ngIf="check"` will show the content if check is **true**

`*ngIf=!check"` will show the content if check is **false**

```
<div *ngIf="!check">Data not available</div>
<ul *ngIf="check">
    <li *ngFor="let user of users">
        {{user.name}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: same thing you have done, I want to show only one thing at a time

Comment: That will show only one thing at a time, as both conditions cannot be true at the same time. It will either show the `true` content or the `false` content.

Comment: @SupriyaKumari please take note of the `!` symbol in the example, as I think you may not have noticed this

Comment: I have added, so it is displaying false value and other is true, but same time

Comment: You can remove the any type for check as it is implicitly a boolean.

Answer (score 0):

Friend, you have done it right just a correction needed in case of Data not available you have to add condition to check whether boolean value is set to  false.
As you have written both conditions same , so it was showing data in both cases. Here, you will check boolean value as false for case - Data not available & if boolean value is true then case - Data is available.

```
<div *ngIf="!check">Data not available</div> // Here false condition syntax  was missing 
<ul *ngIf="check">
    <li *ngFor="let user of users">
        {{user.name}}
    </li>

</ul>
```

Comment: I have written same as you, please check

Comment: @SupriyaKumari This works well, do change datatype of check from any to boolean,
check : boolean = false;

But we also have another way of checking value as , 

```<div *ngIf="(check == false)">Data not available</div>
<ul *ngIf="(check == true)">
    <li *ngFor="let user of users">
        {{user.name}}
    </li>

</ul>
```

Comment: Final result is coming according to true, but before loading true statement for ms false data is also coming

Comment: You need 3 states if you want to have different behaviour while your endpoint is being fetched: `loading`, `success` and `error`. At the moment, because you are using a boolean variable, you only have 2 states, effectively `success` and `error`. So until your endpoint returns the data, you are in the `error` state. Rework the `check` variable to support 3 states and you will be able to display 3 different template behaviours depending on the state.

Comment: @SupriyaKumari Please check my stackblitz - ''https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-c7ngnn?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftop-bar%2Ftop-bar.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Ftop-bar%2Ftop-bar.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts,src%2Fstyles.css ''  in which added your HTML & TS code, its working fine. Let me know if any changes.